# how can I do django custom authorization? I need admin auth by username and password and users by only phone number

Tags: django

How can I realize this code?

admin use only admin panel for authorization
users doesn't use admin panel therefore they use only app for authorization with OTP phonenumber.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifier
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    # oddiy userlar yaratish uchun
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Users must have an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    # supper user yaratish uchun
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

I have manager class and I looked similar code.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I looked some video in youtube I didn't find.

Comment: You need to build custom AuthenticationBackend, see docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend